# Error deserializing JSON credential data. Google Cloud File Upload C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, mongodb

I'm trying to establish connection to google cloud for media upload

I've used various methods like Setting environment variable, saving json to mongodb , tried directly load json from file and then loading to google functions

libraries:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using DAL;  
using MongoDB;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.OleDb;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Configuration;  
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;  
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;  
using System.Drawing;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using MongoDB.Bson;
```

Method 1: Using Environment Variable.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS","onfer-gc.json");  
var Credential1 = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync();  

Error : Using Environment Variable.
Error reading credential file from location onfer-gc.json: Error deserializing JSON credential data.
```

Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Method 2: Load json from file

```
FileStream stream1 = File.OpenRead("onfer-gc.json");
var Credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream1);

Error deserializing JSON credential data.
```

Method 3: Loading data from Mongodb database and then trying to turn into string

```
var Db = new Database();
var result = Db.GetCollection<company>().FindOne(Query.EQ("type", "service_account"));
var Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(result);
```

In this case it gives error

```
Element 'type' does not match any field or property of class MongoDB.company.
```

Even I've checked solutions online
`https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/747`

But it didn't work. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is the json valid ? You can check using: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: Well, the Json is valid. And it worked later on. I don't know what happened but after sometime, "Method 1: Using Environment Variable" worked. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was successfull establishing connection using Method 2:

```
string credPath = "D:\\Admin\\gcloudcred.json";
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(File.OpenRead(credPath));
var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);
listvideos = storageClient.ListObjects("bucketname");
if (listvideos == null)
{
  return listvideos = listvideos1;
}
return listvideos;
```

Comment: Used a variation of the above answer by setting the credentials:  Dim googleCredential As GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(File.OpenRead(credentialsFilePath))

Comment: and then passed the creds to the object: Dim channel = New Grpc.Core.Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials())  Works Great!

Answer (score 3):

My case may not answer the question directly, but it might be possible cause for such error. In my projects I have references to two different versions of Newtonsoft.json, one is 12.0.2 and the other one is 7.0.1. Once I had 7.0.1 updated to same 12.0.2, the json deserializing error solved. This might explain some random working/not-working situations.